# What are the variables in formulating this LP problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

We have $m$ vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $m$ numbers $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_m\in\mathbb{R}$ and we want to find a vector $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|v_i^Ty-t_i|\leq D$ for $i=1,\dots,m$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}$ as small as possible.

I asked before how formulate this as an LP problem of the form

min $c^Tx$

under the condition that $Ax\leq b$,

$x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

A user told me to define the constraints $z_i = \vec{v}_i \cdot \vec{y} - t_i \quad \forall i \in [m]$ and I will want $\min \sum_{i=1}^m |z_i|$.
However this still did not make it clear for me what $c,A,x$ and $b$ are. Can you tell me explicitly what they are?

Comment: Original post here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445438/formulating-an-lp-problem-with-vectors

Comment: I have edited the original post and added a bounty to it, although I think this is a new question.